# avc denial while using Geth android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

This is the error I am getting. Please suggest.

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:19): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs"
ino=1035 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768
tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: https://ibb.co/g96mHQ

Comment: Don't post information of the question as a comment, click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45788219/edit) to edit your question.

Comment: @AbhijeetMalamkar edit your question and post logs as text, not screenshot. It seems that you do not have permission for the file you're trying to access.But we need to know which file you're accessing.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by [SElinux rules](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate), which are enforced since you are not running in *permissive mode* it can be temporary disabled with shell command `setenforce 0` or as kernel boot flags:

```
androidboot.selinux=permissive
androidboot.selinux=enforcing
```

The recommended long term solution is to [edit the SELinux device policies](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/device-policy) and allow usage of the resource.